# How do I find the latest date in each group of a specific value?

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I create a column that has latest date for a specific value of one variable by group? For example, if I have the following table:

```
**Date**|**ID**|**Dummy**
:-----:|:-----:|:-----:
1/1/2021|1|1
1/2/2021|1|1
1/3/2021|1|0
1/4/2021|1|0
1/1/2021|2|1
1/2/2021|2|0
1/3/2021|2|0
1/4/2021|2|0
1/5/2021|2|0
1/1/2021|3|1
1/2/2021|3|1
1/3/2021|3|1
```

How do I get the following table, where the `Latest` column indicates the last date that `Dummy` is 1 for each ID?

```
**Date**|**ID**|**Dummy**|**Latest**
:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:
1/1/2021|1|1|1/2/2021
1/2/2021|1|1|1/2/2021
1/3/2021|1|0|1/2/2021
1/4/2021|1|0|1/2/2021
1/1/2021|2|1|1/1/2021
1/2/2021|2|0|1/1/2021
1/3/2021|2|0|1/1/2021
1/4/2021|2|0|1/1/2021
1/5/2021|2|0|1/1/2021
1/1/2021|3|1|1/3/2021
1/2/2021|3|1|1/3/2021
1/3/2021|3|1|1/3/2021
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Latest date" assumes you have actual dates that can be sorted correctly, so we first need to fix `Date` ... then we group by the `ID` and condition a max on the subset data:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Latest = max(Date[Dummy == 1])) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#    Date          ID Dummy Latest    
#    <date>     <int> <int> <date>    
#  1 2021-01-01     1     1 2021-01-02
#  2 2021-01-02     1     1 2021-01-02
#  3 2021-01-03     1     0 2021-01-02
#  4 2021-01-04     1     0 2021-01-02
#  5 2021-01-01     2     1 2021-01-01
#  6 2021-01-02     2     0 2021-01-01
#  7 2021-01-03     2     0 2021-01-01
#  8 2021-01-04     2     0 2021-01-01
#  9 2021-01-05     2     0 2021-01-01
# 10 2021-01-01     3     1 2021-01-03
# 11 2021-01-02     3     1 2021-01-03
# 12 2021-01-03     3     1 2021-01-03
```

If there's a chance that an `ID` will have zero rows where `Dummy` is 1, then you will get warnings about trying to take the max of nothing; to fix that, we can use a simple conditional:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Latest = if (any(Dummy == 1)) max(Date[Dummy == 1]) else NA) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This behaves the same and provides the same results, but is more deliberate with regards to expectations and `warning`-avoidance.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2021", "1/2/2021", "1/3/2021", "1/4/2021", "1/1/2021", "1/2/2021", "1/3/2021", "1/4/2021", "1/5/2021", "1/1/2021", "1/2/2021", "1/3/2021"), ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Dummy = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```